# How to set up script tags for angularjs 2 written in Es6 for transpilation to Es5

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, systemjs, plunker, traceur

Below is from a plunker that started from the angularjs 2 es6 template http://goo.gl/IGaTZw
I added traceur and removed the main.es6.js replacing with main.js in case the implicit mode was interfering.

```
<head>
<script data-require="traceur-runtime@0.0.88" data-semver="0.0.88" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/traceur-compiler/d3d0553de3315398a956dc2f9edd6a982d786b0a/bin/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.30/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>    

<body>
<app></app>
<script>System.import('main');</script>
</body>
```

Main.js-----

```
import {
  ComponentAnnotation as Component,
  ViewAnnotation as View, bootstrap
} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  viewInjector: [Service]
})
@View({
  template: '{{greeting}} world!'
})
class App {
  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.greeting = service.greeting();
    setTimeout(() => this.greeting = 'Howdy,', 1000);
  }
```

}

```
class Service {
  greeting() {
    return 'Hello';
  } 
}

bootstrap(App);
```

I tried to do locally having downloaded script files but failed there as well.  I cannot use npm etc as have an issue with my laptop.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put enough info and code in your question for people to be able to answer it. Linking out to an external site isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To rectify, include traceur options:

```
 System.config({
   traceurOptions: {
     annotations: true
 }
```

, ( annotations are experimental and have to be turned on manually ) add

```
import { Inject } from 'angular2/di';
```

and change the App constructor argument

```
constructor(@Inject(Service) service).
```

It is also seems possible to have the type in the constructor
    constructor( service:Service) 
dispensing with the inject annotation, as long as you add types:true to the traceur options.